# Show that any vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ can be written as a linear combination of two orthogonal vectors.

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

I must show that any vectors $\vec{w}$ in $\Bbb R^2$ can be written as a linear combination of two non-zero orthogonal vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in \Bbb R^2$ using basic geometry concepts such as the dot product.

So I must prove that $\vec{w} = \alpha \vec{u} + \beta \vec{v}$, with $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$.

The thing is that I don't understand why the two vectors must be orthogonal because if I have :

$\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\
u_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\
v_2 \end{pmatrix}$, two non-zero vectors (let's say $u_1$ and $v_2$ can't be equal to zero).

And I say that $\alpha_1 = -\dfrac{v_2}{-u_1v_2 + u_2v_1}$ and $\beta_1 = \dfrac{u_2}{-u_1v_2 + u_2v_1}$.

I find $\vec{w_1} = \alpha_1 \vec{u} + \beta_1 \vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}$.

With $\alpha_2 = -\dfrac{v_1}{-u_2v_1 + u_1v_2}$ and $\beta_2 = \dfrac{u_1}{-u_2v_1 + u_1v_2}$, I find $\vec{w_2} = \alpha_2 \vec{u} + \beta_2 \vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\
1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore with $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, I can generate $\Bbb R^2$.

Then why would they need to be orthogonal ? Did I miss something or did I do something wrong ? Or maybe I am right ?

Comment: You're right, the vectors ${\bf u}, {\bf v}$ need only be linearly independent for the claim to be true. But, because of the special relationship orthogonal vectors have via the dot product, the formulas for the coefficients are rather simpler when the vectors are orthogonal (and simpler still when they are orthonormal.

Comment: You are not asked to show that the vectors $u$ and $v$ *have to* be orthogonal to generate $\mathbb{R}^2$, you are only asked to show that you *can* generate the space with orthogonal vectors. Of course orthogonality isn't a necessary criterion, but it is sufficient, and that is what you are asked to show.

Comment: @Travis if the two vectors are linearly independent then they would be orthogonal.

Comment: @MaxW Take that, reverse it.

Comment: @MaxW That's certainly not true; for one it would imply that all triangles are right.

Comment: @jahan-claes - you're right. If the vectors are orthogonal then they are linearly independent with respect to the coordinate system.

Comment: orthogonal vectors are linearly independent, so their span is $\Bbb R^n$($n$ is the number of linearly independent vectors), what you did is to prove that  any set of 2 orthogonal vectors are linearly dependent to the Standard basis vectors of $\Bbb R^2$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need orthogonality *per se*, only the fact that $u_{1}v_{2} - u_{2} v_{1} \neq 0$, namely that the vectors are *non-proportional*, or that they form a *linearly independent set*.

Your author (or instructor) is setting you an easier task: If $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal non-zero vectors in the plane, it's easy to show (explicitly using the dot product, without decomposing vectors into Cartesian components) every vector in the plane is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$. Presumably you'll soon generalize, obtaining the same conclusion under less stringent hypotheses.

Comment: Ok thank you. However, I can't seem to see how I should use the dot product to show it in this case. Any hint ?

Comment: Take your equation for $w$ as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ with unknown coefficients; dot both sides with $u$ and solve for the coefficient of $u$; similarly for the coefficient of $v$. Be sure you've used the hypotheses that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal and non-zero. :)

Comment: I don't know why but I found weird to use w = a*u + b*v if that's what we wanted to prove. But anyway, thanks you again.

Comment: The appearance of weirdness signifies good logical instincts on your part: The process looks a lot like assuming what you want to prove. On closer examination, the assumption $w = au + bv$ is part of the "preliminary scratch work" needed to _guess the values of $a$ and $b$_. Then, once you have the (putative) values, it's easy to check they're correct. (You _do_ need to know that "for all vectors $z$, if $u \cdot z = 0$ and $v \cdot z = 0$, then $z = (0, 0)$". Your actual argument proceeds by applying this implication to the vector $z = w - (au + bv)$ for the putative values of $a$ and $b$.)

Comment: Oh, I don't know yet that "for all vectors **z**, if **u⋅z=0** and **v⋅z=0**, then **z=(0,0)**". It was indicated in the exercise to check by calculating the square of the norm of **z=w−(au+bv)** but I didn't succeed in showing it would be equal to zero.